# How to prevent navigation to other screen with react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I hava react native app. And I have a icon. But when the icon is triggered the user will be redirected to a other screen. But the user has to stay on the same screen.

So this part of the component with the icon:

```
<View>
                
                <Card.Actions>
                    <AnimalDetail />
                </Card.Actions>
            </View>
```

And I am using styling.components:

```
export const ButtonDetail = styled.TouchableOpacity`
    background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.bg.primary};
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 9;
`;

export const AnimalDetail = () => {
    return (
        <ButtonDetail onPress={() => console.log("Hello")}>
            <AntDesign name="twitter" size={24} color="green"></AntDesign>
        </ButtonDetail>
    );
};
```

And this is part of the component that the user redirects to a other screen. With this means that if a user clicks on the screen the user will be redirect to a other screen. But for the icon - the user has to stay on the screen.

```
return (
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("groepen", { subcategories: item.id })}>
                            <Spacer position="top" size="large">
                                <CategoryInfoCard category={item} />
                            </Spacer>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
```

Question: how to only trigger the icon and stay on the same screen?

Comment: you are doing navigation so it will obviously redirect to groepen screen, try explain what do u want to perform while onpress event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh... my... I had the wrong import: I had:

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
```

But I needed this import:

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
```

Comment: but still it will navigate to other screen when u do onPress

Comment: @Kishan No it will not. I stay now on the same screen. only the console.log will be triggered. I know. That is the biggest confussion I also had.